# Multi node ELB for DerbyJS

Tags: derbyjs

Possible to use ELB in DerbyJS,i am facing problem in DerbyJS if user 1 connect to instance-A at a same time user2 connect instance-B there is no realtime update between two user

It's possible i can use socket.io adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real-time communication between DerbyJS servers should not be affected by a load balancer (ELB or otherwise). As long as they all connect to the same backend datastore it should work well. This is because the server's use the database (mongo and redis, thru livedb) to communicate changes in data.

Your browser's client connection to the DerbyJS server is by default a long-polling http connection using [browserchannel](https://github.com/josephg/node-browserchannel). browserchannel should work with ELB, you can also setup sticky sessions using something like varnish. We do not recommend socket.io, but rather [racer-highway](https://github.com/derbyparty/racer-highway)